# object Function and object Array - Object.prototype.toString.call

Tags: javascript

Could someone explain this functions?

```
 function b(a) {
    return "[object Function]" == Object.prototype.toString.call(a)
}
```

And

```
function c(a) {
    return "[object Array]" == Object.prototype.toString.call(a)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are borrowing the method `toString` from the `Object.prototype` to find out if the value you are passing into either of the functions is an instance of the `Function` constructor or the `Array` constructor.

Using `toString` directly from the object prototype will override the `toString` on the Array.prototype and the Function.prototype which have different behaviors.

```js
function b(a) {
    return "[object Function]" == Object.prototype.toString.call(a)
}

console.log(
  Object.prototype.toString.call(b),
  b(b)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `toString` on a function, it returns `[object Function]`.
When you call `toString` on an array, it returns `[object Array]`.

The first function checks if whatever is passed in is a function

```js
function b(a) {
    return "[object Function]" == Object.prototype.toString.call(a)
}

var x = b('s'); // false
var y = b(function() {}); // true

console.log(x, y)
```

The second checks if whatever is passed in is an array

```js
function c(a) {
    return "[object Array]" == Object.prototype.toString.call(a)
}

var x = c('s'); // false
var y = c([1,2,3]); // true

console.log(x, y)
```

Because `Object.prototype.toString` is always used, even strings and numbers can be checked this way as it doesn't just call the values own `toString` method